# Why is numpy select is slower than a custom function via apply method?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say, I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c (not a)', 'this is (random)']*10000})
```

I want to produce the following output:

```
array(['same as column', 'b', 'c', 'this is']*10000, dtype=object)
```

Towards that end, I defined the function below and passed it via the pandas apply method.

```
def fn(x):
    if ' (' in x:
        return x.split(' (')[0]
    elif x=='a':
        return 'same as column'
    else:
        return x

df['a'] = df['a'].apply(fn)
```

Then, others advised me to use vectorization, so I used the code below to produce my desired output.

```
df = np.select([df['a'].str.contains(' \('), df['a']=='a'], 
               [df['a'].str.split(' \(').str[0], 'same as column'], 
               default=df['a'])
```

Instead of running faster, this vectorized version ran noticeably slower.

`21.4 ms ± 1.87 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)` for the apply method

`116 ms ± 21.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)` for the vectorization

What's going on here? Is this normal (I thought vectorization was the fastest option available)? Or is there a problem with my code?

Comment: The vectorization claims apply to compiled numpy methods that work with numbers.   Your dataframe elements are python strings, and are processed individually with python string methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You compare different implementations in your benchmark and come to wrong conclusions. The relevant factor is that `pandas` `str` functions are not vectorized but rather implicit loops.

With a colab instance these are the results for your benchmark

```py
%%timeit
df['a'].apply(fn)
```

```
100 loops, best of 3: 8.79 ms per loop
```

```py
%%timeit
np.select([df['a'].str.contains(' \('), df['a']=='a'], 
    [df['a'].str.split(' \(').str[0], 'same as column'], 
    default=df['a'])
```

```
10 loops, best of 3: 51.3 ms per loop
```

If we want to know where the time is spent

```py
%%timeit
df['a'].str.contains(' \(')
df['a'].str.split(' \(').str[0]
```

```
10 loops, best of 3: 48.2 ms per loop
```

And finally comparing python's `string` `split` with `pandas` `str.split`

```py
%timeit df['a'].str.split(' \(').str[0]
%timeit [x.split(' (')[0] for x in df['a'].to_list()]
```

```
10 loops, best of 3: 36.3 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 6.59 ms per loop
```